# Regarding Flush and Shared Variable in openMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp, shared-memory, memory-fences

I want to know when will the private view of shared variables in threads in openMP be written back to memory?

Will it occur only at place where a flush( implicit or explicit) is executed or can they be written back before than?

For example;
at some initial value of i=0 initially;

Now at time=0; thread1 updates values of i=2;

Now at time=1; if thread2 reads values of i, will it always get i=0, because no flush is done by thread1, or might it get i=2